# Where in the official Python docs does it describe __add__ for list type?

Tags: python, list, append, addition

In both the Python 3 and Python 2 documentation, there is no reference to `__add__` for the `list` type.

It exists neither in the [list type description](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) nor in the [special methods section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__).

Do the official docs omit description of the implementation of `+` for `list`?

Comment: [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). It's not specially for list, but for sequence types.

Comment: Thank you - if you post that as an answer I'll tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a documentation for [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

> **`s + t`**:  the concatenation of `s` and `t`

It's not specially for list, but for sequence types.